# Footnotes in list get numbered incorrectly

Tags: xetex, footnotes, friggeri-cv

I am using the friggeri-cv Latex package. I have used footnotes in the following way:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}
%-- ----------------------------------------------
\entry
{2013 -- Now}
{Somename}
{Someplace, Somecountry}
{\emph{Job} \\
Lorem Ipsum
\begin{itemize}
  \item Random[\footnotemark] random
  \item Random [\footnotemark] random
  \item Item
\end{itemize}
}
\end{entrylist}
\footnotetext{One}
\footnotetext{Two}
\end{document}
```

The output I get is this:

```
2.One
2.Two
```

What I expect is this:

```
1. One
2. Two
```

Can someone explain to me what the error is.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done

Comment: `\footnotetext` takes the value of the counter from the last  `\footnotemark` at the time it is executed.

Comment: @Guido:  But if I add     \footnotetext after the     \item, it simply does not appear.

Comment: `\footnotetext` takes an optional argument. So you can write `\footnotetex[1]{One}` for the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Via @Guido:

Problem: `\footnotetext` takes the value of the counter from the last `\footnotemark` at the time it is executed.

As can be seen in the code that I posted above, I had used two `\footnotemark` without a `\footnotetext` in between and thus `\footnotetext` took the count of the last used `\footnotemark`.

I tried to use `\footnotetext` in between `\item`, but then the footnote did not get rendered. See snippet:

```
\item Random[\footnotemark]
\footnotetext{One}
\item Random[\footnotemark]
\footnotetext{Two}
```

The above example did not work, that is, the footnotes did not get render.

The following solution (provided by @Guido) worked for me: `\footnotetext` takes an optional argument. So you can write `\footnotetex[1]{One}` for the first one.

Relevant code snippet:

```
\footnotetext[1]{One}
\footnotetext[2]{Two}
```

Comment: I think, you should elaborate on your answer a little bit. A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Better @ChristianHupfer?